# Galois group of special polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I checked the Galois groups of the polynomials

$f(m,n) := mx^{(n-m)}+(m+1)x^{(n-m-1)}+...+(n-1)x+n$ for $0 < m < n$, and I only found
 one polynomial whose galois group is NOT the symmetric group, namely

$x^{6} + 2x^{5} + 3x^{4} + 4x^{3} + 5x^{2} + 6x + 7$

I have two questions :

1) Is this the only example of a polynomial of the form f(m,n) having 
    not the symmetric group as the galois group ?

2) If a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients has the symmetric group as
    the Galois group, must f be irreducible over Q?

Perhaps, the Galois groups help to show the irreducibility of the polynomials
 $f(m,n)$ for all $0 < m < n$!

Comment: Which are the *dersired properties*?

Comment: For two: pick any polynomial whose Galois group is the symmetric group and consider its square: it has the same Galois group and is not irreducible.

Comment: By the way, we always write Galois with a capital g.

Answer (score 3):

Although I cannot answer the first question (though it seems unlikely to me), the answer to the second question is that the polynomial is always irreducible. You didn't specify which symmetric group, but I assume you mean $S_n$ where $n=\deg(f)$

Assume that $f=gh$. Let $\mathbb{Q}_f$ denote the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. We have

\begin{align*}
[\mathbb{Q}_f:\mathbb{Q}]&=[\mathbb{Q}_f:\mathbb{Q}_g][\mathbb{Q}_g:\mathbb{Q}]\\
&\leq [\mathbb{Q}_h:\mathbb{Q}][\mathbb{Q}_g:\mathbb{Q}]\\
&\leq(\deg(h))!(\deg(g))!\\
&<(\deg(g)\deg(h))!\\
&=(\deg(f))!
\end{align*}

Thus the Galois group can't be $S_n$ where $n=\deg(f)$